# How does MongoDB Compass Schema Analyze work?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

How would you recreate its result? Does it use aggregation only? Or with some code?

Aggregation pipeline operators like `objectToArray` doesn't work with nested key-value. The next easiest way I can think of when dealing with nested key-value is just using the programming language, in my case JavaScript.

What do I have to do in order to get the same result as "analyze" result from "MongoDB Compass > Schema"?